# Python - Recursive way to return a list of the divisors of an integer

Tags: python, recursion

I was trying to write a function that would return the list of a divisors of some positive integer

divisors(12) => [1,2,3,4,6,12]

I did it with a for loop, and then tried to do it with a recursion, but I couldn't figure out how to do it and found no example of it online in any language.

```
def divisors(n,l=[]):
    b=1
    if n < 1:
        return l
    if n == 1:
```

I thought using l=[] would work better than yield, but in any way, I couldn't get anywhere with it.

**Edit:**
using @vks code I wrote the following:

```
def fun(n, l=[],divisor=1):
    if n % divisor == 0:
        l.append(divisor)
    if divisor == n:
        return None
    fun(n, l, divisor+1)
    return l
```

Comment: 1. Please indent your code. 2. I don't see any recursion. Please post your full code and what didn't work.

Comment: Well, I couldn't figure out how to do the recursion, nothing I tried would be of any use.

Comment: Write out your looping function, then at the end of the loop where you mutate some variable (like the list of divisors), recurse instead and pass the list. You'll also probably need a third parameter for your function to keep track of the current denominator, which you'd increment once per recurse.

Comment: I really don't get the code. What you want to do is to write a function taht returns a list of all divisors of a number

Comment: @Glostas yes, that is it, using a recursion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I will try, thanks.

Comment: I guess this is ok as an exercise in recursion, but in general recursion should be avoided in Python unless you really need it (eg for processing a recursive data structure, like a tree) because Python doesn't do [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) elimination (and it limits recursion depth). Also, this technique for finding all factors is very slow for large numbers; there are _much_ faster ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
x=12
l=[]
def fun(n, l):
    if x%n==0:
         l.append(n)
    if n==1:
         return None
    fun(n-1, l)
fun(x, l)
print l
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
>>> n = 12
>>> l = [i for i in range(1, n+1) if n%i==0]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

Comment: While this is a nice answer, I don't think it's recursive.